# SAS - labeled dataset won't open when several sets are simultaneuously imported

Tags: sas

I'm having trouble with merging two datasets. I'm using SAS 9.2 and when importing several datasets they get corrupted and I can only open the last imported set.

```
DATA my_set1;
    SET my_library.my_set1;
    OPTIONS FMTSEARCH = (my_library.labels_my_set1);
RUN;

DATA my_set2;
    SET my_library.my_set2;
    OPTIONS FMTSEARCH = (my_library.labels_my_set2);
RUN;
```

The labels are set like this:

```
DATA labels;
    SET formatted;
    LABEL var_1 = 'label1'
          var_2 = 'label2';
RUN;

DATA labels2;
    SET labels;
    PROC FORMAT LIBRARY = my_library.my_set1;
        VALUE missing_num_labels . = 'Missing';
        VALUE $missing_char_labels ' ' = 'Missing';
        VALUE yes_no_labels 0 = 'No'
                1 = 'Yes'
                . = 'Missing';
RUN;

DATA labels2;
    SET labels2;
    OPTIONS FMTSEARCH = (my_library.my_set1);
    FORMAT var_1 yes_no_labels.;
RUN;
```

I then do the exact same but for my_library.my_set2 instead of my_library.my_set1.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code and the exact error message it gives off? That'll help us figure it out.

Comment: Your SAS code is malformed. PROCs don't go inside DATA STEPS. OPTIONS statements apply to the SAS session, so shouldn't go inside a DATA STEP. Explain what you are trying to do, so we can try to help. Are you trying to merge two SAS data sets? Are you trying to import data into a SAS data set?

Comment: Thank you! Your advice helped me greatly. I realised that the pathway to all labels had to be combined - as you say the proc doesn´t belong inside the datastep. Please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution that worked, as @CarolinaJay65 suggested the OPTIONS is not specific for the dataset.

```
OPTIONS FMTSEARCH = (my_library.labels_my_set1 my_library.labels_my_set2);

DATA my_set1;
    SET my_library.my_set1;
RUN;

DATA my_set2;
    SET my_library.my_set2;
RUN;
```